# Simple JS code bug

Tags: javascript, image, onload, tagname

why dose not it work ? !! 
i want to make images fade out when it is loaded , i know that this can be done by jQuery , but i wanna know where is the bug in this code.

```
<img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-M03SoTLlJ4k/Vfwvq2dz42I/AAAAAAAAD9I/o-xN8x6HL2Y/s1600-r/Untitled-1%2B%25281%2529.png" onload="loadimage()" id="imageid"/>
<style>
#imageid {
opacity:0;
transition:1s;
}
</style>
<script>
function loadimage(){
document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.opacity="1"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you considered [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)'s [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) function? You are doing it wrong with JavaScript. Check the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList not a single DOM node, hence you need to do `getElementsByTagName('img')[0]` for example to get the first img, then apply the styles on that element.

## Update

### select all images

if you want to select all the images and apply styling to them

```
function loadimage(){
   var imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
   for(var i=0, l=imgElements.length; i < l; i++) {
      imgElements[i].style.alpha = 1;
   }
}
```

### only currently loaded image (preferred by me)

```
function loadimage(){
  this.style.alpha = 1;
}
```

Comment: "returns an array" — no, it returns a live HTMLCollection, not an array.

Comment: I didnt want to dive deep in my answer, however HTMLCollections are array-like object similar to arguments, they have object like properties, but can be accessed by index like arrays

Comment: thanks ,, 
but , what about if i want to apply my function on all images which are is the document !

Comment: updated the comment have a look

Answer (score 0):

In javascript,

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')
```

returns a `nodelist`.

If you want the first item in that `nodelist`, you need to write:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
```